# C# System.IndexOutOfRangeException or cant convert to Long

Tags: c#

I'm kinda of having this error:

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException:  Index was out of the Array"

When I change `int=1` to `long=1` it says it can't convert `long` to `int`.

I'm trying to save all output of `N` into the Array and show at the end what is saved into arrays.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 0;
    a = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] array = new int[a];

    if (a == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Falsche eingabe.");
    }
    else
    {
        long n = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= array.Length; i++)
        {
            n *= i;
            array[i] = n;

            Console.WriteLine("N: " + i + " Fakultät von N: " + array[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: longs are bigger than ints, if you had a long that was bigger than int and you tried to convert it to an int, what would you expect to happen?

Comment: `i <= array.Length` is wrong - if `i` is `array.Length` it means it's out of range as arrays are 0 based

Comment: I think knowing if the language you are coding in is zero-indexed or one-indexed is pretty primitive - if you already know that then please learn to debug your problems more carefully.

Comment: @JakubDąbek it makes sense, I change array.Length to just "a". It underlimes the "array[i] = n;" and says the same problem asit was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Indexes of arrays begin from 0 not from one. Therefore in your for loop, `i <= array.Length`, when `i` is equal to the length you enter and try `array[array.Length]` which throws the exception. Change to:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
  ```

  Reason indexes are zero based is that the language is based on C where an array is a pointer to the location that was allocated for the array:

  ```
  int *arrayPointer;
  ```

  And then to go through the array one needs to go to `arrayPointer + sizeof(int)*i`. So for the first position of the array `i` should start from zero
- In addition this line doesn't compile:

  ```
  a = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
  ```

  `a` is of type `int` while you are converting to `long`. Use `ToInt32`

---

Comment: without array[i] = n; line everything works fine without any problem. It works also when i define a as a long and int64 sane as int62 why?

Comment: as long I write array [i] in console.writeline for example Console.WriteLine("N: " + array[i] + " Fakultät von N: " + n); I get that error..

Comment: For the reason I explain - debug and see. At the last iteration of the loop, when `i` equals `array.Length` you get the exception. Because of out of bounds.

Comment: @eXme - Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: no I did not solved the problem. I also tryed same thing with list and having almost same problem System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException dont understand yet, how to solve the problem.

Comment: @eXme - Did you change the loop condition as I suggested?

Comment: no but i found the problem it was in  for (int i = 1; i <= array.Length; i++) and in Console.WriteLine("N: " + i + " Fakultät von N: " + `array[i]`); my i start from 1 and it should start from 0 in array because there is no array[1] in the first loop and only 0 :D so if i declate variable j = 0; and then add array[j++] it works of course as it should be, the fak... part took me whole day lol :D

Comment: @eXme - Yes - because of what I said before. when you access list[i] in a place that is not in the array.

Comment: I didnt get it, im not that advanced in yet doing it for some days only :) but thanks tho if you tho it was like that.